# Method to call words greater than x length

Tags: javascript, methods, iteration

(Firstly, I would like to apologise as I am about a week deep in Javascript (and coding)).

My code is as follows

```
const b = a.method(a => a.length > 7);
```

Essentially I need to change `method` to an iteration (not sure if that's even the correct term) that will create a new variable which only returns words greater than 7 characters.

I know `length` is obviously checking the length, which is great.. but I'm a bit stumped.

Any idea on where I can find a list of methods with easy explanations?

Comment: you're looking for `filter`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter . See the sidebar on that page for the list of all array methods.

Comment: Ah smashing. I did try using MDN but I was obviously looking in the wrong sections. Thanks @gog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your arrow function looks correct, you just need to pass it to `.filter()`

```js
var foo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
console.log(foo.filter(item => (item > 7)));
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Ah perfect - thanks.

Comment: @bce happy to help.